# Visual Web Developer - Reference Paths

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, windows, visual-studio-2010

When I add a reference in VWD 2010 the location of the libraries in the .NET tab is C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0 however, after installing .NET 4.5, the updated libraries are installed to C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319.

How can I set VWD to use this location by default? I'm guessing there is some kind of system setting that tells windows where the .NET libraries are located, but can't find anything about this.